# Как запустить nodejs из файла js? (с интервалом)

Tags: node.js

подскажите пожалуйста
есть файл main.js запускается он node main.js из терминала
каким образом можно запускать эту команду через сетинтервал
(обернуть все содержимое  функцией и потом тригерить функцию ToadScheduler или сетинтервал мне не подойдет)
Вопрос наверное глупый, учу нодежс месяц, извиняюсь)

Comment: cron, npm:scheduler, setInterval

Comment: const scheduler = new ToadScheduler()
const task = new Task('simple task', () => allFn())
const job = new SimpleIntervalJob({ seconds: 120, }, task)
scheduler.addSimpleIntervalJob(job)
у меня есть такой код, каким образом можно запускать не функцию allfn,а main.js файл